# cordova - push notification to device statusbar

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to push notification to the device status bar (like when you receive a text message) http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Back in the old phonegap days I was using https://github.com/nremond/phonegap-plugins-official/tree/master/Android/StatusBarNotification

At some upgrade in time it stopped working.

Now I'm trying to make it work again -
I'm searching the web and all I can find is some broken pieces of code, deprecated plugins, and half answered questions.

Can someone provide a decent example of how to implement it?
i.e. an example of clicking a button and displaying a string in the device notification bar.

please supply end-to-end solution that include:

- which plugin u use
- how u install/config them

some plugin ask for a mysterious SENDER_ID that should 'maps to the project number in the Google Developer Console' (e.g. https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/INSTALLATION.md).

Please explain what is this and how exactly do I get it.

Please supply a Cordova solution (not only phonegap).

Please explain android/ios quirks.

10x.

Answer (score 1):

Latest Push notification plugin https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin is deprecated. You can use the working push notification till the issue for the latest plugin gets fixed. 
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/releases/1.5.2
I had tried with this. It works prefectly fine. 
Download the plugin from the above location and add the plugin to your project using `cordova plugin add *Location of the Locally downloaded plugin*`

Showing the push notification on the statusbar can be done by notifying(invoking) the notification.

Please refer: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md

Downloading the plugin from the location provided above and locally install the plugin.
Push Api has init, register, onNotification, onRegister events.

```
push.on('registration', function(data) {
console.log(data.registrationId);
});
```

This registration id can be used while invoking notification.

```
push.on('notification', function(data) {
console.log(data.message); // Display message data.
```

});

There are several ways of sending push notification. Here I'm using gcm-server to notify.

Create a new file

```
var gcm = require('node-gcm');
var message = new gcm.Message();
//API Server Key
var sender = new gcm.Sender('AIzaSyCDx8v9R0fMsAsjoAffF-P3FCFWXlvwLhg');
var registrationIds = [];
// Value the payload data to send...
message.addData('message',"\u270C Peace, Love \u2764 and PhoneGap \u2706!");
message.addData('title','Push Notification Sample' );
message.addData('msgcnt','3'); // Shows up in the notification in the status bar
message.addData('soundname','beep.wav'); //Sound to play 
message.timeToLive = 3000;

// At least one reg id required
registrationIds.push('APA91bwu-47V0L7xB55zoVd47zOJahUgBFFuxDiUBjLAUdpuWwEcLd3FvbcNTPKTSnDZwjN384qTyfWW2KAJJW7ArZ-QVPExnxWK91Pc-uTzFdFaJ3URK470WmTl5R1zL0Vloru1B-AfHO6QFFg47O4Cnv6yBOWEFcvZlHDBY8YaDc4UeKUe7ao');

sender.send(message, registrationIds, 4, function (result) {
   console.log(result);
});
```

Refer http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/ for clear understanding of gcm-server sending notification.
This will show the notification on the device.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I have tested that only on android. iOS should also support.

Comment: Downloaded plugin is not getting installed for iOS ?

Comment: The plugin you sent is not documented at all, I don't see how this plugin can be use for pushing notification to the status bar - it seems that u mix the terms of push notification - this is exactly what I meant in the question that all the info I found in the web is half answered, and broken plugins, or plugin who do something else with the similar name

Comment: Documentation is updated to latest version. Yes, even I had difficulty in working with push notification. Then downloaded the lowest version of plugin and it helped. My application worked.

Comment: Good for you. but your answer didn't helped

Comment: BTW - did you notice that the plugin you sent is completely not relevant to the question?

Comment: @Joti so you want an example of the implementation showing the notification in device ?

Comment: yes, that was what the question is about, but please note that the plugin you sent is for a different kind of push notification - your plugin is for receiving a notification from a 3rd party, while I was was asking about pushing a notification to the device status bar http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: You can invoke the notification and the user whoever is using the app with that ID will get the notification. Once refer this: http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/ . I will send you an sample implementation of push notification.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109371/discussion-between-bharathv-and-joti).

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer you about the statusbar because I imagine you want to view it when the application is open.
When app is closed, I imagine you already know, the notification is managed by the system in the notification center.

As for the configuration of the SenderID, this is no longer needed. If you are still working on it and want to try setting up a cordova application with push notifications, I suggest you to take a look at [this Guide](https://www.puship.com/cordova-cli/), it is based on a service that also has a free plan. It has a complete guide for both iOS and Android

There is also a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3e3xSeeeiQ&t=53s) that explains step by step how to configure notifications. In the end they show how the messages are shown in the dropdown. If this is what you are searching for, I think it might be for you.